# Why does my loop only work for the first few iterations?

Tags: c, loops, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I am writing a code that simulates a check-out line at a supermarket. I use dynamic allocation (queue) for this problem. 
The current time will run from 0 to 120 minutes (this is also 120 iterations of my loop)
Each customer  will enter the line randomly (the next person will enter after a random integer interval 1 to 4 minutes). The customer will also be serviced by the clerk in a random time manner (after 1-4 minutes). 
The execution looks like this:

----The customer number 1 arrived

-current time is 0

-current time is 1

----The customer number 1 left

-current time is 2

----The customer number 2 arrived

-current time is 3

----The customer number 3 arrived

----The customer number 2 left

and so on.

Function enqueue helps me add the next customer to the line.
Function dequeue helps me remove the customer being served.
This is First In First Out queue.
The first person entered would be the first person that leaves the line.

My question is: My program works perfectly for about 60 or  70 loops. After those loops, I only see people entering the line, and I no longer see anyone leave the line.
How do I fix this loop?
My code is:

```
 struct customer{
int number;  //show the order of the customer waiting on the line
struct customer *nextPtr; //point to the next customer
 };
 typedef struct customer Customer;
 typedef Customer *CustomerPtr;
int main (void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  CustomerPtr startPtr=NULL;
  int timework=0;
  int timein=0;
  int timeout=0;
  int customerio=1;// show the order of the customer entering the line
  printf("\tCustomer number %d arrived\n", customerio);
  enqueue(&startPtr, customerio);
  timein+=rand()%4+1; //schedule the time the next customer will enter the line
  timeout+=rand()%4+1; //schedule the time the next customer will leave the line

while (timework<=120){ // the clerk will serve customers for 120 minutes
    printf("Current time is %d\n", timework);
    if (timework==timeout){ //if the current time matches the time scheduled
        if (startPtr!=NULL){
            printf("\tCustomer number %d left\n", startPtr->number);
            dequeue(&startPtr); //remove a customer from queue
            timeout+=rand()%4+1;
        }
    }
    if (timework==timein){  //if the current time matches the time scheduled
        customerio+=1;
        printf("\tCustomer number %d arrived\n", customerio);
        enqueue(&startPtr, customerio);  //add a customer to queue
        timein+=rand()%4+1;
    }

    timework++; //time elapses to the next minute
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are there downvotes for my question? I have tried my best to explain my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever run into an empty queue, `(statePtr == NULL)`, then you do not update timeout so it will always be less than timework.  Update your code by moving

```
timeout+=rand()%4+1;
```

outside the conditional that checks statePtr.

Alternatively, change your conditional check to `timework >= timeout` but that is arguably less obvious/efficient.

Other solutions are possible - which is correct will depend on the nature of the simulation.